# Copy struct with different type members to buffer

Tags: c, struct, buffer, memcpy

I have a struct carrying multiple members with different type. I want to copy this struct to a buffer, then concatenate a message for later use (separate them and read the struct and message, which I didn't do it here). Here is my code.

```
#define DAT "d"
#define ACK "a"
#define SYN "s"
#define FIN "f"
#define RST "r"

typedef struct Headers {        //total 20 bytes
    unsigned char _magic_[7];   
    unsigned char _type_[1];                        
    union {
        unsigned int _seq_;     //4 bytes
        unsigned int _ack_;     //4 bytes
    } no;
    unsigned int _length_;      //4 bytes
    unsigned short _size_;      //2 bytes
} Header;

int main() {
   Header receiver_header;
   char buffer[1024];

   strcpy(receiver_header._magic_, "ABCDEF");
   strcpy(receiver_header._type_, DAT);
   receiver_header.no._ack_ = 0;
   receiver_header._length_ = 900;
   receiver_header._size_ = 10240;
   char foo[] = "A random message";

   memcpy(buffer, &receiver_header, sizeof(Header));
   strcat(buffer, foo);
   printf("%s\n", buffer);
}
```

And the output is

```
ABCDEFA random message
```

My questions are

1. Do you need to cast the members to same type in order to copy them into the buffer?
2. Why is the rest of the members disappeared in the buffer even I have declared the correct pointer of the source and length of it?

Comment: Even if one assumes that all your assumptions about the size in bytes of `short` and `int` are correct, and that the struct has no padding, how did you count 20 bytes? I counted 18.

Comment: Don't rely on implementation-specifics for communication protocols. Define a machine-independent message format and use correct marshalling with bitshifts/masking to serialise the data. Anything else just calls for trouble. And you should recap the chapter about C-strings and arrays in a C book. Additionally: why take the detour with macros for string literals? Why not use `const` qualified variables directly?

Comment: @StoryTeller it is after padding, it happens after _magic_[7] and _type_[1]. it will be padded with 1 byte in each case so it is 20 bytes in total.

Comment: @Olaf thanks for the recommendation, I will look into it and see what how can I use serialize of data and see if I can do that. I didn't consider of using `const` since I am not familiar the use within struct. The reason why I want to combine both struct and string together is for the other end (receiver or sender) to identify the header. It can of course be done in all string but I want to make it more elegant and easier to use.

Comment: I did not recommend to use `const` for the members, but the original strings **instead** of macros. Never use a macro if a core-language construct will do as well or even better!

Comment: @SpaceWalker - Assuming specific padding is as bad as assuming no padding. The alignment requirements of an array are the same as the requirements of its member. With that in mind, there will most likely be no padding after `_magic_` OR `_type_`.

Answer (score 3):

The first member of your `Header`, `_magic_`, holds 7 `char`s.  You copied 6 `char`s ("ABCDEF") followed by a null character.  `strcat` copies the source string into the destination string at the first null character it encounters.  Therefore, it appends "A random message" right after the first six bytes of the `Header`.  If you want to append the message after the entire struct, you need to specify an offset to copy to, like so.

```
strcpy(buffer + sizeof(Header), foo);
```

However, it won't print the entire struct since the null character is still right after "ABCDEF", even though `foo` has been appended at the correct offset.  If you want to print everything in your struct, just print out each member explicitly, like so.

```
printf("%s %c %u %u %hu %s",
    receiver_header._magic_,
    receiver_header._type[0],
    reveiver_header.no._ack_,
    receiver_header._length_,
    receiver_header._size_,
    foo);
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation of the behavior of `strcat`. So that means if I take away the null character at the end, I then will see `d` as a value after `ABCDEF` inside the buffer?

Comment: @SpaceWalker Yes, if you made `_magic_` 6 `char`s instead of 7, you would see "ABCDEFd" printed, but nothing more since the next byte of the struct is a null character because the next member is an int with the value 0.  This will stop `printf` from printing anything after that.  That's why it's just better to print each member individually so that the presence of null character bytes won't affect the output.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Do you need to cast the members to same type in order to copy them into the buffer?

No.  `memcpy()` can copy the whole representation of any object.  But you do have some other apparent misconceptions and strangeness:

- If `Header._magic_` is meant to hold a *string* then its element type should be `char`, not `unsigned char`.  On the other hand, if it's meant to hold binary data then you should not use `strcpy()` to copy data into it.
- `Header._type_` has space for a single byte, but you `strcpy()` a one-character string into it.  The string requires two bytes when you count the terminator; these don't both fit into `_type_`.  Probably you should perform an ordinary assignment of a single (unsigned) `char` instead.
- The struct representation that you copy into the buffer is not collectively the contents of a C string, if only on account of having internal null bytes.  Therefore, you cannot safely append to it with `strcat()`.  More generally, you ought not be manipulating general data with string functions.
- It is also unreasonable to try to print the structure representation as if it were a string.  Even if there were no internal null bytes, but there were a *terminating* null byte, your struct has numeric fields.  Their representation is binary, not textual, and printing them as if they were textual will not produce anything useful.

> 2. Why is the rest of the members disappeared in the buffer even I have declared the correct pointer of the source and length of it?

Because you overwrote them when you `strcat()`ed the message onto the buffer.

Comment: Detail: A C _string_ is not specified to be of `char` elements.  All string functions handle the elements as if they were `unsigned char` C11 §7.24.1 3 so aside from mechanics of passing data to/from functions, I see no other trouble with `unsigned char` _strings_`.

Comment: @chux, that the string functions are defined to treat string elements as if they are of type `unsigned char` is indeed an interesting detail, but I stand by my assertion.  *As a matter of convention*, not to mention function call mechanics, an array meant specifically to hold a string should be assigned element type `char`.  The standard does not *require* that, but doing so makes intentions clearer.

Comment: Agree `char` is better to convey OP's intention, yet `unsigned char is not in itself incorrect,  good answer.